# How to process an audio signal to mimic it being recorded with a certain microphone

Tags: audio, signal-processing

As of now I am mainly looking into how to process audio in Processing using Java and into various sound libraries that comes with it, such as Beads and Minim primarily (but I am quite flexible to change this depending on what approach would give best results) The idea is to process a sound file in a fashion that the result would sound as if recorded with a certain microphone, for example: If I play an audio file in a space with a microphone that has a very "interesting" response curve, the recording would sound quite different than the original, but instead of recording the original, I could apply a filter to the original signal without using the microphone to make it sound as if it was recorded with it (this, of course, is in the ideal environment and not taking into account the room shaping the sound, etc.)

Currently, I have looked into using EQ, and can apply various filters to the signal in the time domain. I am struggling with implementing an FFT filter, but researching the matter I found a lot of negative comments about it, such as the presence of ripple, pre-echo and smearing of the sound. I then found that the equalizer in Audacity is actually performing eq in the frequency domain and the amount of flexibility it offers (I think) is really what I am after.

However, I have also heard of some VST plugins that do exactly this and some people remark that they use "just" EQ for mimicking a virtual microphone.
So my question then boils down to how to approach this - should I apply a chain of various EQ filters (Beads allows to apply a chain of bandpass, notch, etc. in succession), should I process the audio file in the frequency domain, or is there something else that can be done additionally?

Note again that I do not expect to fully replicate the microphone properties and do not take polar patterns and other things into account - I am looking into the general approach of which characteristics could be extracted and applied.

Comment: Why don't you just calculate a filter response for the microphone in question and then apply it to your signal. You can do it in either domain. Just get the filter coefficients and run them over your signal. Its not easy work. You'll have to get them for few different freq bands. Then you can construct few different filters (one per band) or try to make a good universal approximation from results.

Comment: Thank you for the comment - it sounds a lot like what I should do and what I am trying to do in a way, but being really fresh in the field I'm having a hard time even formulating questions! I know that the Beads library allows passing custom coefficients for constructing a filter, but could you point me in a direction where I could learn more about how to design them/how I would calculate the coefficients for a certain design? Although this perhaps deserves a question on its own...

Comment: If your questions aren't specifically bound to Java i.e. on how to do it in Java, then I suggest you ask them on signal processing stack exchange site instead of here. I never did DSP in Java so I don't know what the libraries are offering. Simple questions as how to calculate coefficients from frequency response are already asked so do a search first. It wouldn't make sense if I post a DSP lesson here. If there aren't examples for Java, find those for matlab or Python, or whatever. functions are usually similarly named. Then read docs for those in Java and write your own code.

Comment: Be prepared for a lot of Maths.  Sounds as though you're planning on using IIR filters.  These generally all have analogue equivalents, and often filter configurations were chosen because it was possible to solve the equation of the filter transfer function. Matlab is usually the tool of choice or this.